# How to save Jenkins Delivery Pipeline Jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Hi i had set up few jobs and linked them through delivery pipeline plugin and had made a pipeline out of it.
But due to some reason (not sure what happened), suddenly my pipelines are not visible in Jenkins and also the plugin was also had disappeared.
But the individual jobs still exist.

Can anyone inform me on how i can save the Jenkins jobs? or the Delivery pipelines created manually?

any help appreciated.

Comment: Is this about Jenkins Pipeline jobs or the delivery pipeline plugin or both?

Comment: This is about Delivery pipeline plugin.